# hide the .xib from the view and again load the previous view?

Tags: ios, ipad

see , i have .h and .m of centerviewcontroller and in viewdidload  i create one tableview and fill that tableview with array data .

After that i load one xib file on centerview and its has one close button , when i click on close button this xib will be close so its hide and my centerview's tableview is again load with data of array .

What can I do ? I am new to ios.

```
- (IBAction)Close_Btn_Pressed:(id)sender
{
     self.view.hidden=YES;
     //its hide the whole view 
}
```

I want to hide the view .... What can I do ?

Comment: how you are showing your view???

Comment: what exactly you want to do?,its not like that xib is totally a different things and view is totally other things

Comment: You will need to specify your NEW VIEW's name instead of self.view.hidden = YES; Something like..... YOUR_NEW_VIEW_NAME.hidden = YES;

Comment: i displayed a nib file on center view and when i click on close button of nib file , my nib file will be hide and my center view is again load to display the control of center view ....

Comment: see , i have .h and .m of centerviewcontroller and in viewdidload  i create one tableview and fill that tableview with array data .

After that i load one xib file on centerview and its has one close button , when i click on close button this xib will be close so its hide and my centerview's tableview is load with data ....

Answer (score 0):

How are you showing your `.xib`? Are you pushing the view in a navigation controller or presenting the view modally?

If you are presenting the `.xib` modally then you can use:

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

otherwise if you are showing .xib using a UINavigationController then you need to

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: see , i have .h and .m of centerviewcontroller and in viewdidload  i create one tableview and fill that tableview with array data .

After that i load one xib file on centerview and its has one close button , when i click on close button this xib will be close so its hide and my centerview's tableview is load with data ....

Comment: i used self.navigation pushviewcontroller:     animated :yes

to load xib on centerview

Comment: Then use it on button action.                                  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];                       Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dismiss your xib from button action use this

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```